# What limits the number of outbound requests an express server inside a Cloud Run container instance can make?

Tags: node.js, express, fetch, google-cloud-run

I have an `express` server running inside a Cloud Run container.

I know a single Cloud Run instance may handle [up to 250 requests concurrently](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#concurrency_values).

[image]

I also know that an `express` server may handle many requests at a time.

But how about outbound external requests that request handlers functions of that server make? What limits that?

Imagine I have an API route, that needs to make a lot of external API calls. For example:

```
/api/update-all-db-with-external-info
```

And the handler for that route is something like this:

**updateAll.ts**

```
import fetch from "cross-fetch";

async function updateAll() {
  const all1000promises = [];
  for (const obj of WHOLE_DB_1000_ITEMS) {
    all1000promises .push(fetch("SOME_EXTERNAL_API"));    
  }
  Promise.all(all1000promises).then((values) => {
    console.log(values);
  });
  // UPDATE DB...
  // DO OTHER STUFF...
}
```

What will limit this kind of code? Is it the memory allocated for the instance? Or is there something like an outbound request concurrency limit for either the `express` server or the cloud run instance?

Comment: What issues you have when you try out the code? Is there an active incoming request handled while doing this code?

Comment: I answered a similar question few months ago, and I'm not able to find it. Anyway, I tested with 10k+ outbound connexion, it was working, but with a too large number of connexion to manage, the CPU capacity is the main limitation. So, you don't have service limit (at least, i didn't reach it), only physical CPU limits